# Why is my Vue template provided with x-template not rendered?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

We have a working Spring Boot application where we use VueJS for the front end part. Currently each Spring MVC template correlates to one vue library.
e.g.
`templates/users.html` includes a `users.js` library built with:
`vue-cli-service build --no-clean --target=lib --name=users --formats=umd-min ./src/vue/pages/users/index.vue`

Simplified template:

```
<div id="vue-wrapper"><users><!-- some stuff rendered on the server (could also be props) --></users></div>
```

And in a JavaScript we create a stupid root instance of Vue:

```
new Vue ({
    el: '#vue-wrapper',
});
```

As we have many pages, we have a vue-cli-service command for each in the package.json. So I wanted to refactor our code and move this to the `pages` in `vue-config.js`.

The problem is, we have some parts that are rendered on the backend so we can't have the template of this root instance be part of the Vue build. So I tried the following:

Template:

```
<div id="vue-wrapper"></div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="vue-tpl">
    <users><!-- some stuff rendered on the server (could also be props) --></users>
</script>
```

I then tried to create the Vue instance like this (we are using TypeScript for Vue):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Users from '@/pages/Users.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#vue-wrapper',
    template: '#vue-tpl',
    components: {
        Users,
    },
});
```

The CSS classes defined in `Users.vue` injected into the head, so the generated `users.js` gets executed, but the template is not rendered, I only see this with inspect:
`<!--function(e,n,r,i){return ln(t,e,n,r,i,!0)}-->`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I created this question after a long search, but shortly after I found the problem; I needed to include the runtime template compiler:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only